# Google Script Get UI textbox value

Tags: textbox, google-apps-script

I have created a simple GUI with 2 textboxes and 1 button.  The button handler goes as below

```
function handleButton1(e) 
{
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var v1 = e.parameter.TextBox1;
    var v2 = e.parameter.TextBox2;
    Logger.log(v1);
    app.getElementById("TextBox1").setText(v2);
    app.getElementById("TextBox2").setText(v1);
    return app;
}
```

When I run the app the textbox values are TextBox1 and TextBox2.
When press button then both the textbox value displayed is undefined.
Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

With a server-side click handler, you need to explicitly include values in the handler event by using `.addCallbackElement()`. If you do so, the current value of the named elements you add will be included in the event delivered to your handler.

Since you are seeing `undefined`, it's likely that you didn't add the callbacks. You should have something like this in your UI definition:

```
var handler = app.createServerHandler('handleButton1')
                 .addCallbackElement(textBox1)
                 .addCallbackElement(textBox2);
button.addClickHandler(handler);
```

The name of the element will be used to label the callback value (`.setName()`), while the id will be used to access the element in your handler (`.setId()`).

Here's a working version of your script:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var textBox1 = app.createTextBox().setName("TextBox1").setId("TextBox1");
  var textBox2 = app.createTextBox().setName("TextBox2").setId("TextBox2");
  var button = app.createButton('Swap Contents');
  app.add(textBox1).add(textBox2).add(button);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('handleButton1')
                   .addCallbackElement(textBox1)
                   .addCallbackElement(textBox2);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function handleButton1(e) 
{
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var v1 = e.parameter.TextBox1;
  var v2 = e.parameter.TextBox2;
  app.getElementById("TextBox1").setText(v2);
  app.getElementById("TextBox2").setText(v1);
  return app;
}
```